# Center and Radius of simple sphere Equation

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

Find Radius and Center Point  of This Sphere

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=6z$$
please i want to understand where this sphere located exactly

The Answer in the book is

> $M(0,0,3), r=3$
>
> can anyone check from this maybe wrong in the book?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: just i want understand from where i can start,i already made an effort but i couldn't get the way

Comment: You should show your work, anyway, so that the answer can reflect your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the equation in the form
$$x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1.$$
Can you work out the centre and radius of this sphere?

Comment: From Where you got $$(z−1)^2$$

Comment: Subtract $2z$ from both sides to get $x^2+y^2+z^2-2z=0$. Then complete the square for $z^2-2z$.

Comment: but this not give me the answer 
M(0,0,3)
 radius = 3

Comment: That isn't the right answer. Perhaps you meant $x^2+y^2+z^2=6z$?

Comment: yes $$x^2+y^2+z^2=6z$$
and the book answer is 
r=3 m(0,0,3)
do you think . answer of the book is wrong ?

Comment: No, for that sphere, your answer is right

Comment: :( from where how ?! .

Comment: thanks alot .................

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in this form $$x^2+y^2+z^2-2z+1=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to $$x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$$
So the center is the point with coordinates $M(0,0,1)$ and the radius is $1$, because this equation describes the set of all points $P(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $$d(P,M)=1$$
where $d$ is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: the answer 
radius  = 3
M (0,0,3)
But I don't know how

Comment: You changed the equation, it´s about completing the square: $x^2+y^2+z^2=6z$ equivalent $x^2+y^2+z^2-6z+9-9=0$ equivalent $x^2+y^2+(z-3)^2=3^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2+z^2&=6z\\x^2+y^2+z^2-6z&=0\\x^2+y^2+(z^2-6z+9)&=9\\x^2+y^2+(z-3)^2&=3^2\end{align}$$

Hence, the center is at $(0,0,3)$ with radius $3$